# Application for emulate user actions

Tags: c#, .net

Is it real in .NET to write an app for emulate user actions? For example, open browser with mouse, type url, press Enter button, click some links, etc.

Of course, before click link i need to find it by href parameter, or smth like that.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and [Watin](http://watin.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010 Premium or Ultimate, there's a type of test project you can create called a [Coded UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681.aspx) test. Coded UI allows you to create UI tests by recording actions and asserting correct behavior.

@oleksii also mentioned Selenium and Watin, which are similar tools.

Of course, if all you want to do is record and play back actions, all you really need is a macro recorder. You can google that term and find dozens of tools that let you record and play back user actions.

## 2019 Update

You should not use Coded UI. It has been deprecated for years. Use Selenium or some other Webdriver-based tool, as Webdriver is a W3C standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# you can use NUnit and Selenium to do browser automation/testing.

I wrote an article about this on http://blog.testingbot.com/2012/01/08/selenium-automated-browser-testing-with-c-and-nunit